# TASCAM DR 100 & Apple Power Adapter

Tags: battery

I read a question here on powering the Tascam with the apple iphone device: connecting the Tascam through usb to an electrical outlet. Some things were not clear to me. 
The dr-100 says 5V. Can i really just plug it in by using USB into my European outlet by plugging a usb cable into my apple power adapter and the adapter into the electrical outlet? Best, soundy

Comment: If you already read the question and answer here, why would you believe the answer a second time around more than the first?  Both the iPhone and DR100 use standard USB power, which is what any USB compliant power adapter should produce.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. this is how I charge mine.